# Map<String, Set<Pathway>> conversion to Map of string to set of one of Pathways properties

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a pathway object like this:

```
class Pathway {
  private dbId;
  private name;
}
```

These pathways are on a map structure of gene, to a set of all the pathways the gene belongs in

`Map<String, Set<Pathway>> geneToPathwayList;`

I want to convert this into a map of `Map<String, Set<String>> geneToPathwayDbId` using streams.

So to do this, I am attempting to iterate over the entry set of the map, collect the keys as the keys, and then collect the values by mapping the set of Pathways to a set of dbIds but I can't get the syntax right. Here is how it currently looks:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> finalMap = 
    geneToPathwayList.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
            e -> e.stream().map(Pathway::getStId).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

I am hung up on how to select `e` as the value from each entry.

Any help in solving this would be greatly helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sounds like you're after

```
e -> e.getValue().stream().map(Pathway::getDbId).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: This did work for me. Its odd because eclipse didn't offer getValue() as a valid method call, but it was still interpreted correctly. I guess it was just the linter not knowing what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @TimB. for what it's worth, IntelliJ seems to have issues with the same thing. Seems to be a bit difficult for IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using for each

```
Map<String,Set<String>> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
   geneToPathwayList.forEach((k,v)-> 
           finalMap.put(k, v.stream().map(Pathway::getDbId).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```